# PHP rename() a file by only its extension

Tags: php

I am trying to rename a file without knowing its' current name and with only the knowledge of its' extension (there is only one file with this particular extension in the directory). Typically, I would just use the asterisk like this:

`rename("users/*.txt","users/testing.txt");`

However, I am getting a warning that no such file exists when I know it does.

Comment: You need to read in the specific file names (using a function such as [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) or [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)) and find each file that is a `*.txt` file and rename it explicitly.

Comment: There aren't. That's why I explicitly noted that in my question.

Comment: Or maybe [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) rather than scandir. But if it returns more than one, you would need to handle that as an error.

Comment: Why not use: exec("mv users/*.txt users/testing.txt"); ?

Comment: *"Typically, I would just use the asterisk like this"* -- *typically*, you use a command with asterisk (like `mv *.txt testing.txt`) in the shell. The shell replaces in the command line the word that contains the asterisk (`*.txt`) with the names of the files that match the wildcard and invokes `mv` with a command line that contains the actual files it founds in the directory and not with the line with wildcards you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve a list (typically of only one filename) of `.txt` files using [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead of attempting to use a wildcard with `rename()`.

In the error-case event that there are more than one file, you get the opportunity to do something to handle the error.

```
// List all text files...
$files = glob("users/*.txt");
$numfiles = count($files);

if ($numfiles == 1) {
  // Rename it
  rename($files[0], "users/testing.txt");
}
else if ($numfiles > 1) {
  // Something is wrong - there are too many text files
  // error handling...
}
else {
  // no text file, no action, or raise an error if it's missing...
}
```

Comment: You are correct and in fact, my actual code uses `glob()` but since I was not having issues with that, I thought it'd be best to show an example as succinctly as possible. Thanks for your help.